# Union of the results with an empty LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

In the database, I have some of the products and prices.
I need to search for the price limits. The problem is that there may be several limits. For example, 0 - 500 $ 1500 - $ 2000

How to merge this LINQ queries

```
var products = from product in db.Products
where product.Price >= 0 and product.Price <= 500

var products = from product in db.Products
where product.Price >= 1500 and product.Price <= 2000
```

My varriant:

```
  IQueryable<Deal> allResults = null;
            for(var i = 0; i < price.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
             {
              decimal start,end;
              decimal.TryParse(price[i], out start);
              decimal.TryParse(price[i+1], out end);

              var tempResults = from product in query
                         where (product.DiscountPrice >= start && product.DiscountPrice <=                    end)
                       select product;
                    tempResults.Union(allResults);
                }
```

how to create an empty query to join ?

Comment: do you want a union or a join? they are two different functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to merge the conditions:

```
var products = from product in db.Products
where (product.Price >= 0 and product.Price <= 500)||product.Price >= 1500 and product.Price <= 2000
```

Another is to use `Union` or `Concat`:

```
var products = (from product in db.Products
                     where product.Price >= 0 and product.Price <= 500)
         .Union(from product in db.Products
                     where product.Price >= 1500 and product.Price <= 2000);
```

Adapting your code on can do:

```
IQueryable<Deal> allResults = null;
for(var i = 0; i < price.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
{
    decimal start,end;
    decimal.TryParse(price[i], out start);
    decimal.TryParse(price[i+1], out end);

    var tempResults = from product in db.Products
                      where (product.DiscountPrice >= start && product.DiscountPrice <= end)
                      select product;
    if(allResults!=null)
       allResults=allResults.Union(tempResults);
    else
       allResults=tempResults;
}
```

You don't need an empty query in to merge with, you can just add a special case that tests if this is the first query.

But I don't like that code much, because it mixes two concerns: The construction of the queries, and the merging of the queries. So I'd split it in two:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<Decimal,Decimal>> ParsePrices(string[] rawPrices)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < price.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
    {
       decimal start=decimal.Parse(price[i]);
       decimal end  =decimal.Parse(price[i+1]);

       yield return Tuple.Create(start, end);
}

var prices=ParsePrices(rawPrices);
IEnumerable<IQueryable<Deal>> partialQueries=prices.Select( interval=>
       from product in db.Products
       where (product.DiscountPrice >= interval.Item1 && product.DiscountPrice <= interval.Item2)
       select product;);
var mergedQuery=partialQueries.Aggregate((q1,q2)=>q1.Union(q2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty query using `Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable()`.

An issue you have in your code: `Union` does not alter any of the sequences that you pass to it as parameters; rather, it creates a new sequence which it returns. Thus, you should be assigning the result of your `tempResults.Union(allResults)` operation to `allResults`.

Here is some sample code (not tested):

```
IQueryable<Deal> filteredResults = Enumerable.Empty<Deal>().AsQueryable();

for (int i = 0; i < price.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    decimal start, end;
    decimal.TryParse(price[i], out start);
    decimal.TryParse(price[i+1], out end);

    var tempResults = from product in db.Products
                      where product.DiscountPrice >= start && product.DiscountPrice <= end
                      select product;

    filteredResults = filteredResults.Union(tempResults);
}
```